# Getting latest version of all projects in Eclipse using P4Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, perforce, p4eclipse

I wonder if there is a way to get the latest version of all the projects in Eclipse from Perforce by one click. It's kind of cumbersome to select them all and do that. Is there a way for that?

Thanks,

Tomer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended workflow (well in my honest opinion of using Perforce for many years) is to always have P4V open alongside your IDE. Perhaps this is just cautionary as the integration plug-ins (especially P4SCC) sometimes do things without your knowledge or function a little bit differently.

Getting latest on all projects using P4V is a simple right-click on the root folder and 'Get latest...'.

**In response to the comment:** There could be an option to do so, however I'm unfamiliar with the P4 Eclipse integration. My answer was to make the point that the workflow is better when you use both the IDE integration and supplied client; from my experience (which is several years of using Perforce) you cannot rely only on the integration to do everything.

HTH,

Comment: I want to contact P4 only from the Eclipse plugin... So I guess there is no such an option, is it?